# The function name does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

The following Windows service code is trying to call the `copyej()` method, which will complete the required task, but when I am calling this function in my timer it throws out the following error :

> The name copyej() does not exist in current context

Although it is defined in a public class not sure why it is having this issue, here's the complete code :

```
/** Using Config File for Directories **/
using System.Configuration;
//====Read From Access namespace===============
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.OleDb;
//using System.IO;
//=============================================
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Configuration.Install;

namespace Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples
{
    // Define a service contract.
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples")]
    public interface Copytask
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void copyej();
    }

    public class CopyejService : Copytask
    {
        // Implement the Copy EJ methods.
        //  CopyejService copyej = new CopyejService();
        public void copyej()
        {
            // Functionality Derivation
            string target_dir_file = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["TargetDir_File"];
            string target_dir = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["TargetDir"];
            string text_dir = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["TextDir"];
            string file_name = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["FileName"];
            string source_dir_file = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SourceDir_File"];

            // Check if Target Directory Exists            
            DirectoryInfo theFolder = new DirectoryInfo(target_dir);

            if (!theFolder.Exists)
            {
                theFolder.Create();
            }

            /*
            if (!File.Exists(target_dir_file))
            {
               // MessageBox.Show("Function Exited");
                return;
            }*/

            // Delet if EJ file exists
            if (File.Exists(target_dir_file))
            {
                File.Delete(target_dir_file);
            }

            // Copy the EJ file in Target Directory
            File.Copy(source_dir_file, target_dir_file);

            //=============Extract contents in Access and save it as Text File Format==========================================
            string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\test\TestEJFolder\BWC_Ejournal.mdb";

            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            OleDbConnection conn1 = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            OleDbConnection conn2 = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

            string sql = "SELECT * FROM Events";
            string dt = "SELECT TOP 1 [Date] FROM Events";
            string count = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Events";

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
            conn.Open();
            OleDbDataReader reader;
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(dt, conn1);
            conn1.Open();

            OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(count, conn2);
            conn2.Open();

            string time_stmp = Convert.ToDateTime(cmd1.ExecuteScalar()).ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
            string s_path = text_dir + "\\" + time_stmp + "_" + "Session" + "_" + file_name;

            FileInfo oFileInfo = new FileInfo(source_dir_file);

            string fname = "File Name: \"" + oFileInfo.Name + "|" + " ";
            string fsize = "File total Size: " + oFileInfo.Length.ToString() + "|" + " ";
            string fdts = "Date and Time File Created: " + oFileInfo.CreationTime.ToString() + "|" + " ";

            Int32 r_count = (Int32)cmd2.ExecuteScalar();
            StreamWriter sp = File.CreateText(s_path);
            sp.WriteLine(fname + fsize + fdts + "Record Count " + r_count);
            sp.Close();

            conn1.Close();
            conn2.Close();

            string path = text_dir + "\\" + time_stmp + "_" + file_name;
            StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path);
            const string format = "{0,-22} {1,-4} {2,-4} {3,-4} {4,-20} {5,-22}";

            string line;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                line = string.Format(format, reader.GetDateTime(5).ToString(@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").Trim(),
                    reader.GetInt32(0).ToString().Trim(),
                   reader.GetInt32(1).ToString().Trim(),
                   reader.GetInt32(2).ToString().Trim(),
                   reader.GetString(3).ToString().Trim(),
                   reader.GetString(4).ToString().Trim());
                sw.WriteLine(line);
            }

            reader.Close();
            conn.Close();

            sw.Close();
            sw.Dispose();
            //====End Of Extract Access contents and save it as Text Format=========================================================
        }
    }

    public class CopyEJWindowsService : ServiceBase
    {
        public ServiceHost serviceHost = null;
        public CopyEJWindowsService()
        {
            // Name the Windows Service
            ServiceName = "CopyEJWindowsService";
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            ServiceBase.Run(new CopyEJWindowsService());
        }

        private System.Timers.Timer serviceTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            InitTimer();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            serviceTimer.Stop();
        }

        private void InitTimer()
        {
            serviceTimer.Start();
            serviceTimer.Enabled = true;
            serviceTimer.Interval = 5000;
            serviceTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnServiceTimerElapsed);
        }

        public void OnServiceTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)
        {
            serviceTimer.Enabled = false;
            try
            {
                copyej();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Handle exception
            }
            finally
            {
                serviceTimer.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
    // Start the Windows service.

    /*
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
     {
         if (serviceHost != null)
         {
             serviceHost.Close();
         }

         // Create a ServiceHost for the CopyEJService type and 
         // provide the base address.
         serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CopyejService));  

         // Open the ServiceHostBase to create listeners and start 
         // listening for messages.
         serviceHost.Open();
     }

     protected override void OnStop()
     {
         if (serviceHost != null)
         {
             serviceHost.Close();
             serviceHost = null;
         }
     }
    }*/

    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public class ProjectInstaller : Installer
    {
        private ServiceProcessInstaller process;
        private ServiceInstaller service;

        public ProjectInstaller()
        {
            process = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
            process.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
            service = new ServiceInstaller();
            service.ServiceName = "CopyEJWindowsService";
            Installers.Add(process);
            Installers.Add(service);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need an instance of your `CopyejService` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copyej is in the class `CopyejService`.
So to call it, you should instantiate that class, and call it as a method.

```
CopyejService myObject = new CopyejService();
myObject.copyej();
```